# Service Temporarily Unavailable Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When I tried to open my WordPress site, it shows the error below:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>
> Additionally, a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Can anyone help me get out of this error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be a programming problem. You should talk to your hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).
- resetting the plugins folder by FTP or PhpMyAdmin. Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems.
- re-uploading the wp-admin and wp-includes folders from a fresh download of WordPres